# Replace strings in a dictionary with integers (from a text file)

Tags: python, string, dictionary, integer

I have values (this are the sentiments: "negative", "neutral", "positive") from a text file. The keys are the adjectives. I want to produce a dictionary with the adjectives and new values, namely -1, 0, 1.

This is what I produced so far:

```py
dictionary = {} #creating an empty dictionary
infile =  open('adjective_sentiment.txt', 'r')
for line in infile:
  key, value = line.split()
  dictionary[key] = value
  print(dictionary)
```

How can I access the values and replace them with the numbers?

[image: This is the screenshot from the text file]

Comment: Please add a sample of the 'adjective_sentiment.txt' file

Comment: I meant in the question, not as a comment

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
D = {'negative': -1, 'neutral': 0, 'positive': 1}
dictionary = dict()
with open('adjective_sentiment.txt') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        a, s = line.split()
        dictionary[a] = D[s]
print(dictionary)
```

Of course, this could go horribly wrong if the file is not formatted **exactly** as stated